Microsoft Excel stays on splash screen and does not start
I am having trouble with Microsoft Excel starting up. For some reason, Excel will not start, it opens the splash screen and appears to be loading indefinitely. This is true of a new Excel instance as well as when opening an existing file. If I run Excel with the /E flag, it will open. Then, once opened, any document will open.
What might cause this behavior and what can I do to remedy this?

have you tried repairing excel?

Are you using Excel 2016 (MSI version) and windows 11 24h2? If so, it seems to be a hot issue. You need to open the Excel application first and then open the file. Or you roll back to older version of Windows.
